# Working with Subsets - Difference in pairs (array)

Tags: java, arraylist, subset, quicksort

I am attempting to write a program that takes an array, effectively sorts the array viaquickSort, then for each pair in the sorted array with a specified difference passed by an integer paramter (via the parameter in the method), it outputs pairs based on the specified difference. The method effectively returns an ArrayList with integer pairs that are different. E.g. let's assume i have an array that's like {16, 12, 7, 8, 4, 13, 9, 20}. The method would sort it then if the integer passed is 4, the pairs it would return are

(4,8) (8,12) (9,13) (12,16) (16,20)

For some reason though, my code is not doing that, I'm getting a run-time error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space 
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3210) 
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3181) 
at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:261) 
at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:235) 
at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:227) 
at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:458) 
at DifferencePairs.findPairs(DifferencePairs.java:20) 
at DifferencePairs.main(DifferencePairs.java:72)
```

Here is my code, and what i have done:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DifferencePairs {
    public static ArrayList<Pair> findPairs(int[] array, int diff) {
        /*
         * sort the array. This takes O(n log n) (quicksort)
Then for each x in array A, use binary search to look for difference in elements. This will take O(logn).
So, overall search is  O(n log n)
         */
        sort(array);
        int i = 0;
        int j = 1;
        int sizeOfArray = array.length;

        ArrayList<Pair> differencePairs = new ArrayList <Pair>();
        while (i < sizeOfArray && j < sizeOfArray) {
            if (i != j && (array[j] - array[i] == diff)) {

                Pair newPair = new Pair(array[j], array[i]);
                differencePairs.add(newPair);
            } else if (array[j] - array[i] < diff) {
                j++;
            } else if (array[j] - array[i] > diff){
                i++;

            }
        } return differencePairs;             
    }


    public static void sort(int[] arr)
    {
        quickSort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
    }
    /** Quick sort function **/
    public static void quickSort(int arr[], int low, int high) 
    {
        int i = low, j = high;
        int temp;
        int pivot = arr[(low + high) / 2];

        /** partition **/
        while (i <= j) 
        {
            while (arr[i] < pivot)
                i++;
            while (arr[j] > pivot)
                j--;
            if (i <= j) 
            {
                /** swap **/
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;

                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }

        /** recursively sort lower half **/
        if (low < j)
            quickSort(arr, low, j);
        /** recursively sort upper half **/
        if (i < high)
            quickSort(arr, i, high);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         int[] myArray = {16, 12, 7, 8, 4, 13, 9, 20};
         ArrayList<Pair> pairs = findPairs(myArray, 4);
         for (Pair pair: pairs) {
             System.out.println(pair.toString());
         }
    }               
}
```

and this next Class is the Pair class in case you are wondering. Please kindly tell me where I'm going wrong. Thanks!

```
public class Pair {

    private int first;
    private int last;

    public Pair(int first, int last)
    {
        this.first = first;
        this.last= last;

    }
    public int getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public void setFirst(int first) {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public int getLast() {
        return last;
    }

    public void setLast(int last) {
        this.last = last;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "(" + this.first + " , " + this.last+ ")";
    }


}
```

Comment: Using a HashMap would be a much better approach for this problem.

Comment: I understand that, but for the sake of this my solution must be O(n log n) and not O(n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an infinite loop in the while loop that creates the Pair objects. That's why you're running out of memory.

I beleive you need to increment i and j in the first condition of the while loop:

```
while (i < sizeOfArray && j < sizeOfArray)
{
    if (i != j && (array[j] - array[i] == diff))
    {
        Pair newPair = new Pair(array[j], array[i]);
        differencePairs.add(newPair);

        // increment both here
        i++;
        j++;
    }

    // rest of loop
}
```